# TensorFlow: GPU not fully utilized while training BLSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create an end-to-end trainable offline English Handwriting Recognition Model (without segmenting individual character). The word dataset from IAM Handwriting Database is being used for training the model.

The model is training very slowly and the GPU utilization hovers around just 30%. Also getting a PoolAllocator warning -

```
PoolAllocator: After 89632424 get requests, put_count=89632402 evicted_count=175000 eviction_rate=0.00195242 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00195474
```

Tried changing the batch size but to no avail. The data is being fed through a TFRecords file (could it be causing an issue?). I am new to TensorFlow so could have made some naive error. The code used:

```
class Config():
im_height = 28
num_epochs = 25
batch_size = 1

# Rnn
rnn_num_hidden = 256

# Number of classes
num_classes = 81

tfrecord_filename = 'sequence_data_lengths_3_4.tfrecords'

config = Config()

class CRNN(object):

def __init__(self, config):

    self.config = config
    tf.reset_default_graph()

def read_and_decode(self, filename_queue):

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Define how to parse the example
    context_features = {
        'length': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
        'out_length': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    }
    sequence_features = {
        'token': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.float32),
        'labels': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
        serialized=serialized_example,
        context_features=context_features,
        sequence_features=sequence_features)

    image = sequence_parsed['token']
    label = tf.cast(sequence_parsed['labels'], tf.int32)
    length = tf.cast(context_parsed['length'], tf.int32)
    lab_length = tf.cast(context_parsed['out_length'], tf.int32)

    image_shape = tf.cast(tf.stack([self.config.im_height, 
                                    length/self.config.im_height]), tf.int32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)

    # Updating length to represent image width
    length = tf.shape(image)[1]

    # Batch the variable length tensor with dynamic padding
    self.images, self.labels, self.lengths, self.lab_lengths = tf.train.batch(
        tensors=[image, label, length, lab_length],
        batch_size=self.config.batch_size, dynamic_pad=True)

def net(self):


    batch_lab_length = tf.reduce_max(self.lab_lengths)
    batch_im_length = tf.reduce_max(self.lengths)

    # Reshape to time major
    sequences = tf.reshape(self.images, [batch_im_length, self.config.batch_size,
                                            self.config.im_height])

    # Feed sequences into RNN
    with tf.name_scope('RNN'):
        self.cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.config.rnn_num_hidden,
                                       state_is_tuple=True)
        self.cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.config.rnn_num_hidden,
                                       state_is_tuple=True)
        self.output, self.state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
            cell_fw=self.cell_fw,
            cell_bw=self.cell_bw,
            inputs=sequences,
            dtype=tf.float32,
            sequence_length=self.lengths,
            time_major=True,
            scope='RNN'
        )

        # Reshaping to apply the same weights over the timesteps
        self.output = tf.reshape(self.output, [-1, self.config.rnn_num_hidden])

        self.out_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.config.rnn_num_hidden,
                                                 self.config.num_classes],
                                                stddev=0.1), name='out_W')
        self.out_b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., shape=[self.config.num_classes]), name='out_b')

        # Doing the affine projection
        logits = tf.matmul(self.output, self.out_W) + self.out_b

    # Reshaping back to the original shape
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [self.config.batch_size, -1, self.config.num_classes])

    # Time major
    logits = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2))

    # Training computation

    # Prepare sparse tensor for CTC loss
    labs = tf.reshape(self.labels, (self.config.batch_size, batch_lab_length))
    sparse_tensor_indices = tf.where(tf.less(tf.cast(0, tf.int32), labs))

    labels_vals = tf.reshape(self.labels, [batch_lab_length*self.config.batch_size])
    mask = tf.cast(tf.sign(labels_vals), dtype=tf.bool)
    labels_vals = tf.boolean_mask(labels_vals,mask)

    labels_sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices=sparse_tensor_indices, values=labels_vals, 
                                    dense_shape=[self.config.batch_size, 
                                                 tf.cast(batch_lab_length, tf.int64)])
    self.loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels_sparse, logits, sequence_length=self.lab_lengths, 
                          preprocess_collapse_repeated=False, ctc_merge_repeated=False, 
                          time_major=True)
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(self.loss)

    # Optimizer
    self.optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01,
                                           momentum=0.9, use_nesterov=True).minimize(self.cost)

    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
    self.train_prediction = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(logits, 
                                                sequence_length=self.lab_lengths)


def train(self):
    num_steps = int((self.config.num_epochs*self.config.sample_size)/self.config.batch_size)
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
                    [self.config.tfrecord_filename], num_epochs=self.config.num_epochs)

    self.read_and_decode(filename_queue)
    self.net()

    # The op for initializing the variables.
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                       tf.local_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        training_summary = tf.summary.scalar("training_cost", self.cost)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./TensorBoard/graph", sess.graph)

        sess.run(init_op)
        print('Initialized')
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        start = time.time()
        steps_time = start

        epoch = 1
        for step in range(num_steps):
            _, c, predictions, actual_labels, train_summ = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.cost,
                                                                     self.train_prediction, 
                                                                     self.labels, training_summary])
            writer.add_summary(train_summ, step) 


            if (step % 10000 == 0):
                preds = np.zeros((predictions[0][0].dense_shape))
                i =  0
                for idx in predictions[0][0].indices:
                    preds[idx[0]][idx[1]] = predictions[0][0].values[i]
                    i+=1
                print(time.time() - steps_time)
                steps_time = time.time()
                print('Minibatch cost at step %d: %f' % (step, c))
                print('Label =', [''.join([char_map_inv[j] for j in i]) for i in actual_labels], 
                      'Prediction =', [''.join([char_map_inv[j] for j in i]) for i in preds])

            if (step!=0 and step % int(self.config.sample_size/self.config.batch_size) == 0):
                print('Epoch', epoch, 'Completed')
                epoch+=1

            last_step = step
        saver.save(sess, "model_BLSTM", global_step=last_step)
        writer.close()
        print(time.time() - start)

model = CRNN(config=config)
model.train()
```

Comment: Do you execute your training from command line, or from a debugger? I noticed that when I execute the training in debug mode, then the training becomes much slower

Comment: I am executing it from a debugger, will revert with the results after doing it from the command line.

Comment: Tried it out. No change in performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because TensorFlow's CTC implementation does not support GPU (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2146).

Using Baidu's CTC GPU implementation (https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc) resulted in an increase in GPU utilization and sped up the training.